# Vue-datetime plugin format time and date output to readable value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using this [vue-datetime](https://mariomka.github.io/vue-datetime/) plugin, my problem is I'm unable to parse the output to a more readable value

```
<datetime v-model="time"></datetime>
```

return value is

> 2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z

even using momentjs returns invalid date?

```
moment('2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z').format('hh:mm');
```

I just want the value like time 08:30. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You're using the Moment.js API incorrectly. Try `moment(this.time).format('hh:mm')`

Comment: @Phil ow, my bad, it just a wrong typo. Still not working

Comment: what do say about `moment(new Date('2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z')).format('hh:mm');` ?

Comment: Works fine for me. `moment('2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z').format('hh:mm')` prints _"09:06"_ which is correct for my timezone

Comment: @AliD. yours is working, post it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @JuliverGalleto - posted an answer. Thanks for your offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following:

```
moment(new Date('2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z')).format('hh:mm');
```

Answer (score -1):

after installed luxon

```
npm install --save luxon
```

You can also use it like this

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
...
console.log(DateTime.fromISO('2019-06-27T11:06:00.000Z').toFormat('hh::mm'))
```

and the output

```
06:00
```